# Push ViewController with transparent background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I want to have a blurred image as a fixed background in my app. My ViewController structure is like this:

HostViewController (with background image and VisualEffectView)
– NavigationController (modally presented over the HostViewController)
–– ViewController (with clear background color)

When I want to push to another ViewController (which has also clear background color) from the NavigationController, the new ViewController overlaps the first ViewController which is visible through the new ViewController. That looks quite strange and ugly. My question is how I could achieve a push animation with a fixed background without the ViewControllers overlaying each other?

You can see a sample of this effect in the app "TuneShell" which can be found in the App Store.

Thanks in advance, Fabian.

---

**EDIT:**
To clarify my problem I added this gif:

[image]

As you can see in the gif, when I push to the Playlist-ViewController, the rootViewController is visible through the new Playlist-ViewController while it's animating. I want to fix that.

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE:**

[image]

Comment: You have to add the background in the window in AppDelegate.m inside -didFinishLaunching.

Comment: @0yeoj thank you, but that wasn't my real problem. I have edited my question so you might understand my problem better.

Comment: ahh.. i see.. have you tried setting `self.view.alpha = 0` inside `-viewWillDisappear`?

Comment: @0yeoj yeah, I tried it, but that wasn't the effect I wanted to achieve. I edited my question again.

Comment: The clips to bounds property for the view might not be set for the first view. If you do that, this will be fixed. You don't have to go through such customization as mentioned in the answer just to fix this issue. If thats what you want.

Comment: @GoGreen if you set the viewClipsToBounds property for the view of the viewController, which initiates the push segue to the next viewController, to true this problem doesn't get fixed. The to views still overlay each other.

Comment: Could you try setting clipsToBounds to the other view??

Comment: @GoGreen that doesn't work either. I will stick to the answer by 0yeoj, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have a solution for this way back, but I don't think this is the best one and keep in mind that this is just a workaround.

First thing to do is set your `global` background like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ..
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blur.jpeg"]];

    return YES;
}
```

`blur.jpeg` is a clear(not blurred) image I'm using this for example (got it from google)

[image]

Next is subclassing `UIViewController` for global use, but its up to you how to implement it globally.

```
//BGBlurViewController.h
//
@interface BGBlurViewController : UIViewController

@end

//BGBlurViewController.m
//
@implementation BGBlurViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIToolbar *background = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [background setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    [self.view addSubview:background];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:background];
}

@end
```

I'm using `UIToolbar` as a background of `UIViewController` and achieve blur effect.

---

This is how to use the subclassed `UIViewController`(BGBlurViewController)

```
//RootViewController
//
#import "BGBlurViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : BGBlurViewController

@end
```

and another:

```
//View next to rootViewController
//
#import "BGBlurViewController.h"

@interface ViewController2 : BGBlurViewController

@end
```

NOTE:
I'm setting the backgroundColor of the `UIViewController`s (ViewController and ViewController2) to `Default`/none in storyboard, again this is just a workaround...

---

Here is the sample output in runtime:

[image]

Hope this would help you.. Cheers..

Comment: @FTFT1234 quite a clever trick :) Do you know what's going on behind scenes? Why it only works with a UIToolbar? Have you since found a less "workaround-ish" solution :)?

Comment: @ospr; actually it doesn't work ONLY with UIToolbar you can use UIImageView with a translucent image, but I prefer using UIToolbar. What's really happening is that he don't really want the `self.view` to be fully transparent instead cover the viewcontroller behind it while keeping the translucency... if you guys find some better trick, do let me know, just for my edification.

Comment: @0yeoj cool. Yeah it seems like the UIToolbar is always showing the window's background in the correct position as you are animating between the view controllers. It seems like there's something special going on in that view. I tried a UIImageView with a translucent image and had the original issue FTFT1234 had above where the bottom view controller shows behind while transitioning. Unfortunately, my use case requires the view controllers to be modally positioned over a background view controller and the UIToolbar trick doesn't seem to work. Will let you know if I find anything else.

Comment: You made my day, don't know how you found this trick ! There's definitely something special going on with this UIToolbar, the background is fixed when user dynamically swipe back so it's not a "normal" background added behind